C# WASM JSImport callbacks
I'm using the JSImport feature for calling JavaScript from Blazor. It works fine, but I'm struggeling to understand the lifetime of callbacks.
For example I can add a callback/listener like this:
[JSImport("addListener", ModuleName)]
public static partial void AddListener([JSMarshalAs<JSType.Function<JSType.Object>>] Action<JSObject> callback);

Which works just fine, but what is the lifetime of 'callback' on both the .NET and JavaScript sides? Am I causing memory leaks if I do not explicitly dispose something?
The documentation says: (Link)

You can pass Action/Func callbacks as parameters, which are
marshalled as callable JS functions. You can pass both JS and managed
object references, and they are marshaled as proxy objects, keeping
the object alive across the boundary until the proxy is garbage
collected.

I don't understand what a "proxy object" is in this context. It is a .NET or JavaScript object?
When inspecting the created JavaScript function it seems to have a dispose() function, but that doesn't really match with "until the proxy is garbage collected". I'm a bit lost...
